# get value out of block (iOS 5)

Tags: ios

I want to return this method to array but the value out of block always nil...

so how can it return to array with the data in block ? the data (JSON) inside block is valid.

```
+ (NSArray *)getFoods {

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_FOOD]];
__block id array = [NSMutableArray array];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    array = JSON;
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
return array; --> nil
```

why the normal way is so easy but the block way is a little difficult ? I change my code and dont use block in this method:

```
+ (NSArray *)getFoods{

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kFoodPlaceFoodsURL];
if (data != nil) {
    NSDictionary *foods = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    return [foods mutableCopy];
}
NSLog(@"No Data !!!");
return  nil; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation executes asynchronously; but you are returning the `array` synchronously.  The operation's success block will be executed at a nondeterministic time; but your `return` statement is executed immediately after `[operation start]`.

Another issue:
(1) You don't provide a failure block for the operation; so if the request fails, you won't know.

Try logging `JSON` within the success block first.  Confirm that you are getting back valid data (and that the request succeeds.)  If not, provide a failure block and look at what the failure is.

But above all, you'll have to redesign this API to account for the fact that the `AFNetworking` API's are asynchronous.

Comment: I can do successfully with synchronously and without block (use NSURLConnection) but i wanna try asynchronously. so I use AFNetworking. the data in side block is valid, and I have checked it but the data outsite always nil. the failed I will set it later because I need get the data first.

Comment: Yes, the data inside the block might be valid, but it probably comes AFTER the return since it is async.  To test this, set two breakpoints, one inside the block and one on the return statement.  I will bet that the return statement comes first.

Comment: thanks, I understand the return come first and the block will execute later so the return can not get the data. so how am I solve this problem ? so its impossilbe to get data ?

Comment: It's not impossible to get the data, you just have to work with it in a way that accounts for the asynchronous nature of the API you are working with.  Without knowing more about how what you are doing, it's hard to be more specific than that.  But, as a start, your success block needs to do something other than set a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:` is asynchronous, which means that the success block will be executed *after* your `NSLog` statement.

Comment: yup, thats why the return always nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the object that calls sends the getFoods message as the delegate method of the class that has the getFoods method.  Then in the AFJSON success block just do something like:

```
[delegate didReceiveJSON:JSON];
```

Of course you'd have to define the delegate protocol and methods.